# dllregisterserver in iviewers failed

Tags: regsvr32, oleview

When I try to run Oleview I get an error saying that DllRegisterServer failed for IViewer.dll (sorry I wanted to post a screenshot but I can't until I get 10 reputation =p)

Oleview will run but like the msg says, you can't look at interfaces which is exactly what I want to do.

I found my iviewer.dll and ran regsvr32 on it just fine.  So I'm not sure whats up.

Answer (score 112):

Ack, should have done more due diligence. Found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=dllregisterserver%20in%20iviewers%20failed&ac=8) on msdn which explains that you need to run Oleview as admin. Stupid UAC.

I tried it out and running as admin works for me.

Answer (score 13):

You only need to run it the first time as admin. Make sure you open a tlb file though, so it registers IVIEWERS.DLL as COM server into the registry. After that you can run it as a normal user. This is explained in the Windows SDK readme, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you only need to run Oleview as Admin the first time. I can confirm it worked that way for me.